# how to track plays on Yahoo Web Player with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I have Yahoo Web Player on my site (http://floortracks.net/), and I'm trying to track the plays using Google Analytics event tracking. You can see the player pop up when you click on a play button on the front page.

Does anyone have tips on how to track plays with the Yahoo Web Player implementation? One thing I found on the Google Analytics product forum is that, apparently, there's some tracking code built in already. It's this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var track_count = 0,
track_total;
YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onAPIReady.subscribe(function(obj) {
YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onPlaylistUpdate.subscribe(function() {
track_total = YAHOO.MediaPlayer.getPlaylistCount()
});
YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onTrackComplete.subscribe(page_changer);
});
function page_changer(obj) {
track_count++;
var pg = jQuery('a[rel="prev"]').attr('href');
if (track_count >= track_total && pg) document.location = pg;
}
// ]]></script>
```

Does anyone know how to use this to track the file plays using Google Analytics or something similar? I don't know what to make of this code.

Or is there some other way to track plays through Yahoo Web Player that I'm missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you move off of the Yahoo Web Player as [Yahoo doesn't support any more](http://yahoo.tumblr.com/post/54125001066/keeping-our-focus-on-whats-next). However, I was able to dig up some api documentation on the api methods, and add some play tracking for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var track_count = 0, track_total;
    YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onAPIReady.subscribe(function(obj) {
        YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onPlaylistUpdate.subscribe(function() {
            track_total = YAHOO.MediaPlayer.getPlaylistCount()
        });
        YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onTrackComplete.subscribe(page_changer);

        YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onTrackStart.subscribe(function(){
        ga('send', 'event', 'Music Player', 'Play', 
});
    });

    function page_changer(obj) {
        track_count++;
        var pg = jQuery('a[rel="prev"]').attr('href');
        if (track_count >= track_total && pg) document.location = pg;
    }
// ]]>
</script>
```

I was able to find the original [Yahoo Media Player API documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20110927040053/http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/api/#event_onTrackStart) using wayback machine - hope this helps.